# Want Mybatis to insert booleans as Y,N, not 0,1

Tags: mybatis

I'm writing a class instance to a MySQL DB using MyBatis

```
// I have no control over how this java class is laid out -.-
class Hello {
    boolean isFriendly
}
```

my MyBatis Mapper looks like this

```
<insert id="doHello" parameterType="Hello">
    insert into hello_table (
        is_friendly   --this is a varchar(1) btw
    )
    values (
      #{isFriendly}
    )
 </insert>
```

The problem is it inserts the values into the DB as 0 or 1, but I need to have it as 'N' or 'Y'
and I don't have the choice of modifying the java

I'm trying to keep my code as minimal as possible and ideally would like to add stuff into the Mybatis Mapper

I tried things like

```
 #{isFriendly,jdbcType=Boolean}
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your insert statement

```
insert into hello_table (
        is_friendly
    )values (${isFriendly=="0"?"'N'":"'Y'"})
```

Comment: thanks, thats exactly what I did. I hoped there would be some 'clever' setting in mbatis where it would just output as N or Y, as it is I've got 15 copies of that line all over my code. But sound solution. thanks

Comment: In fact I added 
values ( if( #{isFriendly} =0,'N','Y')

but it amounts to the same thing

so you get the big green tick. well done + thanks

Answer (score 4):

MyBatis typeHandler is a proper way to do it.

You could implement a type handler and then use it in any sql statement:

`#{isFriendly, typeHandler=YesNoBooleanTypeHandler}`

For the details see [MyBatis Java Boolean to Sql enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474296/mybatis-java-boolean-to-sql-enum)

Answer (score 0):

create handler and add it in Mybatis configuration
create handler:

```
    import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
    import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
    import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;
    import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;

    import java.sql.CallableStatement;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    @MappedTypes(Boolean.class)
    @MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.CHAR)
    public class BooleanStringTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler {

        @Override
        public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, Boolean aBoolean, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
            preparedStatement.setString(i, aBoolean ? "Y" : "N");
        }
        @Override
        public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String s) throws SQLException {
            return getBoolean(resultSet.getString(s));
        }
        @Override
        public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            return getBoolean(resultSet.getString(i));
        }
        @Override
        public Boolean getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
            return getBoolean(callableStatement.getString(i));
        }
        private Boolean getBoolean(String s) {
            return "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(s);
        }
    }
```

add it in your Mybatis configuration:

```
<typeHandlers>
    <typeHandler jdbcType="CHAR" javaType="java.lang.Boolean" handler="crm.data.trade.utils.BooleanStringTypeHandler"/>
</typeHandlers>
```