# is it possible to convert values from boolean to "Y" / "N" when we save or update

Tags: java, mapping, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using mybatis with xml mappings. It so happened, that in my database I have to store boolean values in string format like : "Y"/"N". In my java code I have a lot of lines, like `setValue( someBooleanValue ? "Y" : "N" );` Is there any way to store boolean values and then all these values convert to "Y" : "N" ? Maybe I can define a method or function for converting?
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I suppose it's out of the question to change your database schema to something more sensible?

Comment: You can write your own mapper to do this

Comment: not allowed to change schema(

Comment: Doesn't your database support if/etc. in your statements? So you could simply map your boolean way to Y/N inside your insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [TypeHandlers](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) for this.

> Whenever MyBatis sets a parameter on a PreparedStatement or retrieves
>   a value from a ResultSet, a TypeHandler is used to retrieve the value
>   in a means appropriate to the Java type.
>
> You can override the type handlers or create your own to deal with
>   unsupported or non-standard types. To do so, implement the interface
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler or extend the convenience class
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler and optionally map it to a JDBC
>   type.

A more complete example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13487957/821786).